# How to stop a event (mineflayer)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

(new to js)
I am making a discord to minecraft bot which uses discord.js on one file and mineflayer for the minecraft bot. When a command is run in discord, it makes the bot run it and runs a function which detects the right line in chat, problem is even after it detects the message, it constantly stays on and reads every line, forever. Meaning if someone else types what its detecting it interferes and thinks thats the right chat line..

Im not sure how to make it stop either, after running the event once, or after finding the line in chat, I would probably need it to stop after running it once incase the line doesnt show up for some reason.

```
function balOutput() {
  bot.on('message', jsonMsg => {
    if (Array.isArray(jsonMsg.json.extra)) {
      var message = '';
      jsonMsg.json.extra.forEach(function(element) {
        message = message + element.text;
      });
      if (message.toLowerCase().includes('\'s balance')) {
        var msg = message;
        fs.writeFile('output.txt', msg, err => {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      } else if (message.toLowerCase().includes('is not locally online')) {
        var msg = 'That player is not online!';
        fs.writeFile('output.txt', msg, err => {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
      }
    }
  continue;
  });
}
```

That function is called once the discord command goes through and it runs it in minecraft. It does work for the one time but then other messages ruin it. The problem is I cant just use regex and make it detect that message of a player saying it because, some other commands need to run with the exact same output but be placed in different spots, so I need it not to trigger the bot.on('message') in the baloutput function... Pretty much I need to close that event after running it once.

Comment: When this function executes, the `bot.on()` now listens for every message that comes in. I assume you call this function when a specific command is executed? If so, why not just remove the `bot.on()` and pass the function the message so it can work with that?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not entirely sure what `jsonMsg` represents, as Discord.js’s `message` event passes a `Message` object as its first argument, and that doesn’t have a `.json` property, while you are expecting `jsonMsg.json.extra` to be an array, and that seems to be the case sometimes.

However, whenever you call your `balOutput` function, it seems you are adding yet another listener callback function to `bot`’s `message` event. That could be causing the behaviour you’re faced with, where things only work the first time. You’ll want to add just one callback.

You may also want to look into using a normal `for` loop, rather than a `.forEach()`, from which you can break out of with `break;` the moment your `if` condition is first met.